# what if index access fails in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to access a scalar value in a multi column dataframe via a lookup as follows:

```
targetDate = '2016-01-01'
df['revenue'][df['date']== targetDate].values[0]
```

Now, in my case there is nothing found in the dataframe for the `targetDate`. So I get the following index error:

```
IndexError: ('index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0', 'occurred at index 69322')
```

Is there a pandas built-in way to gracefully result in `np.nan` in such cases? How would you handle such a situation?

I don't want my script to fail when nothing is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `Series` is empty and then add `if-else`:

```
targetDate = '2016-01-01'
a = df.loc[df['date']== targetDate, 'revenue']
print (a)
Series([], Name: revenue, dtype: int32)

if len(a) == 0:
    print ('empty')
else:
    first_val = a.values[0]
```

Similar solution with [`Series.empty`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.empty.html):

```
if a.empty:
    first_val = np.nan
else:
    first_val = a.values[0]

print (first_val)
```

Comment: Okay so just standard exception handling...   I thought perhaps there was something built into pandas. No worries. I will follow ur advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you precede with `head(1)` and remove the subscript on values then that will avoid the error message although it won't fill with a nan (it will just be an empty numpy array).

```
df['revenue'][df['date']== targetDate].head(1).values
```

But you could do something like this to get a nan instead of empty.

```
df['revenue'][df['date']== targetDate].append(pd.Series(np.nan)).head(1).values
```

Or do it as a `try/except` or an `if/else` as @jezrael does.  Lots of ways to do this, of course, just depends on what is convenient for you.